# TeX Live on Lubuntu

Tags: installing

How come there is no information on the internet on how to install the latest TeX Live version on the latest Lubuntu version? Or even earlier versions? There is only information on Ubuntu installation. Can TeX Live run on Lubuntu? If not, why has it not been developed?

Comment: Lubuntu is just Ubuntu with another DE.... just use the Ubuntu resources you already found...

Comment: the upstream texlive from tug is a generic linux binary not specific to any linux distribution.

Comment: Specifically the guide at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864 should be good for all Ubuntu-based (and more generally even most Debian-based) distributions. This includes Lubuntu.